# Storing code to copy workbook from closed WB in personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to copy 4 worksheets from a closed workbook with the following code, although I'd like to store this code in personal.xlsb so it would be available in every new instance of excel WB that I open. And my issue starts here as if I run the code from personal.xlsb it returns an error

> Run time error '1004': Copy method of Sheets class failed

and the debugger is highlighting this line:
`wbSource.Worksheets(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).Copy Before:=wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Can someone help me solve this?

```
Sub CopySegSheets()

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\PATH\sourcewb.xlsx")
wbSource.Worksheets(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).Copy Before:=wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1")
wbSource.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Thanks BigBen, unfortunately this change didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does the activeworkbook have a sheet called `"Sheet1"`? Same error message?

Comment: Maybe don't name the sheet.  ```Before:=wbTarget.Worksheets(1)```

Comment: @BigBen, yes it does have, actually it's a brand new workbook with only that one sheet named "Sheet1".

Comment: @roses56 , unfortunately that didn't work either. Thanks for trying though.